# How can I put the Dashboard icon on my dock in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos

I have no Dashboard icon in my Dock.

How can I put it on my Dock as there is no option to 'Keep in Dock' that I can find?

Answer (score 3):

Any app that is currently running can be pinned to the dock by right clicking it, and choosing `keep in dock`, but occasionally you find a program like Dashboard or Mission Control or Launchpad etc that overlays the dock area when running thus not letting you add it.  The simplest solution is to find the application within your `/applications` folder, and simply drag it to the dock, where it should add a suitable shortcut that stays put.

However, I would generally advise for these sort of program that remembering the keyboard shortcut or trackpad gesture is often much faster and results in a less cluttered dock.

Comment: A less cluttered dock is a more efficient dock.